# Regex Too Slow Need To Optimize

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am using a regex expression like "a.{1000000}b.{1000000}c" to pattern match on a string. However this is WAY too slow. Is there a better way to do this? I am not interested in the stuff between a, b and c, as long as their gap is of my specified size I care not of the content within. One can think of it as skipping n characters. Checking the index doesn't serve me well either, I need to be using some built-in method written in C. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you need a, b, and c to be spaced by a million chars?

Comment: Well yes, `.{1000000}` will capture the text into memory and increase consumption. Also the max size for quantifiers is `65535`.

Comment: Are you looking to just verify that something is in that pattern or want to extract the value of a, b, and c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to verify that a string is in a given pattern and do not care to extract the a, b, nor c then this would work:

```
(?=^a.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}b.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}.{50000}c$)
```

The limit for regex quantifiers is `65535` so if you need one million then you would have to repeat `.{50000}` 20 times like I did above.

Now you just need to make Python code that says "if regex match then proceed"

Regex101 takes 68ms so I would consider that to be "fast".

https://regex101.com/r/q6RgNJ/1

Comment: @dospyth Then how did you conclude that `.{1000000}` is slow if you didn't run into the limitation?

Comment: @dospyth That's the problem when you withhold information and present a theoretical question; you get an answer not applicable to your specific situation. You should present your actual attempt because I have no idea if your regex for a, b, and c is the slow part or maybe your file reading is slow and you're blaming regex.

Comment: @dospyth If you don't need the `^` and `$` anchors then don't use them.